# Alternatives to using UINavigationController toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have an app with multiple views that uses a navigation controller. On some of the views, I need a toolbar with buttons that pertain to that view. While I have successfully added custom buttons to certain views' tool bars, I am having a big problem maintaining the state of those tool bars. For example, when navigating to a view that has a custom toolbar, all of the other views in the app seem to inherit that toolbar's state. For example, view 'A' needs a toolbar with button 'X'. This works as planned. However, when navigating to view 'B', view A's toolbar is loaded into view B.

I have tried deconfiguring the toolbar on viewDidDisappear with limited results. When using this method, there is latency in removing the custom items. For example, when navigating to another view, the buttons don't disappear until the next view has loaded.

Really, all I need is a toolbar that stays at the bottom of the view and does not scroll away when the user scrolls the view. It seems the only way to achieve this is to lock it into a navigation controller's toolbar. However, this approach creates numerous other issues including those mentioned above.

Again, the behavior I am looking for is to have a toolbar that is always at the bottom of the view and is independent from the scrolling of the view/tableview. Is there a way to achieve this without using a navigation controller? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your app structure a bit? Do you have a navigation controller as the root view controller, and your pushing and popping to go between controllers (no scrolling as you say in a couple of places)? Where did you add the tool bars? To each controller? To the navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, i have a navigation controller as the root view controller. i want the custom toolbars to remain in view if the user scrolls the view. I added the toolbars to each view controller's navigation bar

Comment: 1. I think what you need is a TabbarController 2. You can use a ViewController with a TableView instead of a TableViewController to constrain the Scrollable Area.

Comment: To remain in what view? You want A's toolbar to remain with A, and B's to remain with B? Again, Ill ask about scrolling. Are you actually scrolling (using a UIScrollView), or are you talking about the transition you get with the plush and pop?

Comment: I'm using a tableviewcontroller. Yes, i want A's toolbar to remain with A, B's toolbar to remain with B...

Comment: I don't understand why you're having a problem then. If you add a toolbar to A, and a different toolbar to B, then when you navigate back and forth between them, the toolbars do remain with their respective controllers. I've tested this, and I don't see the problems you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution: Implement these methods in A ViewController.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for this property: **hidesBottomBarOnPush** (available on the SB)? You set this property to YES on every **navigation controller's** view but the A.